# Is the hierarchy of the precedence of testimony only dependent on the category of scripture?

Tags: scripture, vedas, puranas, gods, itihasa

It is generally believed that Vedas can override Epics if needed and Epics override Puranas if needed.

But a recent question arose - "in the same scripture is there a hierarchy of testimony , perhaps something like God > Deva > human ?

Does any scripture address this?

Comment: even by adding 'does any scripture address this' the question is still opinion based.

Comment: Epics override Puranas - where did you hear this? AFAIK, Itihasa and Puranas have the same authority..

Comment: No scripture will address this, because otherwise, different portions of the same scripture will have different authorities, and which is absurd of course... Even if gods are speaking in a scripture, one needs to understand that the scripture was authored by a human being (a Rishi, to be precise).

Answer (score 1):

> Does any scripture address this?

A scripture wouldn't address this, otherwise there will be circularity, but logical genius Yamunacharya has phenomenally answered this in his [*Agama Pramanya*](https://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Agama%20Pramanyam%20%5BSkt-Eng%5D#page/n185/mode/1up).

He says that the pramanya of the Vedas comes from it being unauthored, and so its validity cannot be questioned. However, he then says something interesting. Normally one would think that an authored text (Smriti) is less authoritative than the Vedas, but Yamunacharaya says that **a scripture authored by Brahman would have the same level of credibility as the Vedas themselves.**

According to him, Narayana is Brahman and he authored the Pancharatra Agamas. Since Narayana is omniscient and full of compassion to his devotees, the Pancharatra Agamas are equivalent to the Vedas.

The Agamas and scriptures promulgated by other gods and rishis are to be rejected since they contradict the Vedas and Pancharatra Agamas:

> How can the teaching of Vasudeva himself, who is well-known in Shruti and Smriti, be brought to the same level as other Tantras? - p. 36
>
> ...
>
> This argument cannot be extended to other tantras, for in the various authors of those Tantras (Shiva, etc). error is possible.

He then goes on to say that Shiva, other gods, Rishis like Kapila, etc are beings still bound by karma, and hence error in them is possible, but not in the supreme Brahman. Therefore, their tantras should be rejected *wherever they contradict the Vedas and Pancharatra Agamas.*

**He even says that if there was a conflict between the Vedas and Pancharatra Agamas, there would be option!**

> Therefore, the real ground for the thesis that the validity of the doctrine of the Bhagavan and that of the Veda is above question is this: that both are causes of defectless knowledge. Consequently, because both are equally exemplary, they are optionally valid. - p. 94

From this it is clear that the truth of a statement really depends on who authored that statement.